# How can I make Save & Close the default action instead of Save

Tags: magento2

When editing a product from the grid. We make changes, save and want to go back to the grid by clicking 1 button.

**Question**: How can I make Save & Close the default action instead of Save

Should Magento have a config option to make Save and Close the default acion? Or should it be Save and Close by default (instead of currently Save)

[image: Testing at https://heerenzaak.nl]

Answer (score 3):

I've replaced these options via my custom module - I'm using the latest Magento 2.3.5.

Follow my steps - all paths inside **app/code/Vendor/Module** (change the namespaces to yours if you want):

1 - **registration.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

2 - **etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_ConfigurableProduct"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

3 - **etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save">
        <plugin name="change-save-options"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save" />
    </type>
</config>
```

4 - **Plugin/ConfigurableProduct/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/Save.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save as ConfigurableProductSave;

class Save
{
    /**
     * @param ConfigurableProductSave $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetButtonData(
        ConfigurableProductSave $subject,
        array $result
    ): array {
        $result['label'] = __('Save & Close');
        $result['data_attribute']['mage-init']['buttonAdapter']['actions'][0]['params'][0] = true;

        foreach ($result['options'] as &$option) {
            if ($option['id_hard'] == 'save_and_close') {
                $option['label'] = __('Save');
                $option['data_attribute']['mage-init']['buttonAdapter']['actions'][0]['params'][0] = false;
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to run **setup:upgrade** and **setup:di:compile**.